# java "if" and "if-else" performance

Tags: java, performance, conditional-statements

I´m wondering if there is a difference between this statement.

```
public String returnSomething() {
  String result = null;
  if(isOK) {
    result = "YES";
  }
  result = "NO";
  return result;
}
```

and this one

```
public String returnSomething() {
  String result = null;
  if(isOK) {
    result = "YES";
  } else {    
    result = "NO";
  }
  return result;
}
```

Which one has the best performance? Which one is the best practice?

Comment: The first one has a bug, the second one hasn't.

Comment: if you're just returning then what's wrong with 'return isOk ? "YES" : "NO";'

Comment: If you don't return in the first if the two are fundamentally different.

Comment: Have you tried running your own tests? That would be a good starting point, rather than asking for people's "opinion".

Comment: Why is everybody so obsessed with the performance of such minor code nowadays?! We are talking nano seconds with 'if' statements, it would be practically impossible for human to notice any difference whatsoever! May I ask why you are actually asking this question?

Comment: @Andy: Agree completely. The only way this could even matter is if this code (corrected, of course) were being executed billions of times, with not much else going on.

Answer (score 4):

Both are not equal when `isOK == true`. The first method will return "NO", the latter "YES".

If you put the assignment before the if in the first example, they will return the same result.

Comment: I hope that is a typo in the question!

Comment: oh I'm sorry the first example was supposed to be like this

      if(isOK) {
        result = "YES";
        return result;
      }

Answer (score 3):

If you go a level deeper and see at the microprocessor level, the if and else conditions are just fast enough since they simply skip addresses and jump to a different address consisting of the instruction set. So in the above scenario both are equally fast.

However the first case would always return a "NO" irrespective of what isOK is and hence I would say it is wrong, technically.

Answer (score 2):

Leave aside the performance the two constructs are logically different.
They are not the same.

In first case the `result` will be set to `No` irrespective of first `if` condition is `true`.
In second case the `resut` will be set to `No` only if the first `if` condition is not `true`.

Basically, You are trying to compare Apples and Pears here.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good use-case for the *conditional operator* (also sometimes called the *ternary operator*):

```
public String returnSomething() {
    return isOK ? "YES" : "NO";
}
```

The performance of this should be the same as any other reasonable approach, but this approach is more concise and in my opinion is much easier to read (assuming you know about the conditional operator).

Answer (score 2):

This is no significant difference in performance. But there is a difference in meaning. 
Your first snippet is buggy. It always returns `"NO"`. I believe you wanted to write the following:

```
public String returnSomething() {

  String result = null;

  result = "NO";
 if(isOK) {
    result = "YES";
  }

  result = "NO";

  return result;
}
```

And BTW such pre-mature optimization (and even thinking about such kind of optimization) can cause problems. The readability of code is much more important. Your code can be rewritten as the following:

```
public String returnSomething() {
  return isOK ? "YES" : "NO";
}
```

I think it is much more readable, simple and easier for maintenance.

Comment: first code is still buggy, need to delete the 2nd `result = "NO"` line. I also would prefer the 2nd, but I learned that its readability is questionable...

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to do is as follows:

```
public String returnSomething() {

  String result = "NO";

  if(isOK) {
    result = "YES";
  }

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first one will be slower because you are doing two assignments here as @ALS points out above.

That's because the code is incorrect :)

Answer (score 1):

For you first method, the result always set to "NO".

Answer (score 1):

You should never do this level of micro-optimization!

Chances are you'll spend your time getting to an answer with the accuracy of flipping a coin. Even if you write a test to benchmark it, almost all such benchmarks are written without a proper understanding of which code is actually executed in the JVM. The compiler optimises your code for you, and it's likely far better at it for micro-optimization, which can lead to different code running than what you wrote.

Even if you do find which is faster, the difference will be so negligible it cannot possibly cause your software any issues. So any genuine performance problems are elsewhere. I sincerely doubt that the difference between these would be much more than 100 ms for a million such operations.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you thought of for the first example looked like this:

```
public String returnSomething() {
    if(isOK) {
      return "YES";
    }
    return "NO";
}
```

Hence no need to create a temporary variable! And there is no difference with the second example.

EDIT: I know this is only a sample code, but you might want to follow a certain convention when it comes to naming member variables (e.g. isOK -> m_isOk)